# How much memory do I need to allocate for an array of X strings of 50 characters?

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory, malloc

I need to make an array of strings for a program in one of my CS classes.  We are to just assume that the length of all the strings is no more than 50 (this accounts for the null character).

I need use `malloc()` or `calloc()` to allocate the proper amount of memory for the array, but I am new to C and I don't really know how to use those functions.

The real question I guess is how much memory to I need do allocate for an array of x strings of 50 characters.

Comment: \0 is the null terminator or null character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\0` is called the termination character for strings.

What you need is array of char pointers.

```
char *strArrayPtr[X]; // X needs to be a compile time constant.
                      // C99 supports variable length arrays too.
```

Now each index holds pointer to an array that is allocated by `malloc(50)`;

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char *ar[2] ;
    ar[0] = "Hello";  // This needs to malloced memory in your case
    ar[1] = "World!"; // i.e., ar[0] = malloc(50);

    printf("%s", ar[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My X will be changing.  What it is, is the number of words from three different files.  I need to merge all the words from each of the files into a 2D array then sort it for output to a new file.

Comment: @Michael -  With the given ideas, first start working out. SO is there to help you when you are struck :)

Comment: Ok, I guess I just don't really know how to use `malloc()`, am I supposed to figure out the whole array size right away?

`malloc(X * (however many bytes a char takes) * 50)` 

It's supposed to be a 2D array.

Comment: **"I need to make an array of strings for a program in one of my CS classes..."** Now with the given description and what you are doing with `malloc` doesn't match. `malloc(X * (however many bytes a char takes) * 50)` doesn't give you an array that can hold **strings**. It just gives a contiguous sequence to hold characters.

Comment: @Michael - If you're using a `char **` (which is the simplest to understand) you'll need two (sort of) calls to `malloc` - one to allocate the pointers that the `char **` points to, and then one (in a loop) to allocate each `char *` (these are the actual 50-char strings) in the `char **` array. (You can do it in one allocation, but understanding how to make it work is pretty tricky, and if this is homework your teacher may not be very happy with the code you'll write to make it work.)

Comment: I think that is more of what I need.  From what I've learned about strings in C, they are way different from strings in the other languages I know.  My biggest problem is I don't know how to use `malloc()`.

Comment: @Michael If you want to know how to use a specific function, refer to its declaration and specification, which may give you some insight. See this for `malloc` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/

Comment: @Mahesh - Do I need to run a `for` loop to `malloc(50)` each spot in the array?  And after that will, say, `ar[34]` access the whole string?

Comment: @Michael - Yes, you are correct. Take a look at this example http://ideone.com/NlX1G

Answer (score 3):

Assuming type `char`, at minimum you will need `X * sizeof(char) * 50`.

If you are doing all of these allocations separately, there will be overhead for each allocation. So the total amount of memory in this case will be higher.

This overhead is unspecified and can be fairly large.

But I wouldn't worry about that for a homework assignment. I can't imagine the problem needing enough memory to possibly run your system out.

Comment: If you're talking about the terminating NULL, the OP stated that it's already included in the 50.

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` (requirement of C standard, if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a variable-sized array of fixed-size strings:

```
char **arr = calloc(len, 50 * sizeof(char));
```

Don't forget to free the memory!

```
for(unsigned long i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    free(*arr++);
```

---

You're not going to be dynamically pushing elements, are you? If so, we're going to have to get a bit more complicated. (I'd add a `StringArray::capacity`, to speed up `push`, but I don't want to overcomplicate things... Seeing as how I suck at C, if you look at the comments below. ;))

```
struct StringArray
{
    char** arr;
    unsigned long len = 0;
};

StringArray StringArray_init(char** arr = NULL, unsigned long len = NULL)
{
    StringArray a;
    a.arr = arr;
    a.len = len;
    return(a);
}

void StringArray_push(StringArray *a, char* str)
{
    if(len == 0)
    {
        a.arr = StringArrayInit(malloc(sizeof(char*)), 1);
    }
    else
    {
        a.len++;
    }

    a.arr = realloc(a.arr, a.len * sizeof(char*));
    a.arr[a.len - 1] = malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(a.arr[a.len - 1], str);
}

void StringArray_free(StringArray a)
{
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < a.len; ++i)
        free(a.arr[i]);
}

StringArray szArr = StringArray_init();
StringArray_push(&szArr, "This is a string.");
StringArray_free(szArr);
```

---

It's a heck lot easier with C++. :)

```
std::vector<std::string> arr;
arr.push_back("This is a string.");
```

Comment: a) You forgot `return a;` in `StringArray_Init()`. b) You _can't_ allocate a `char **` with a single `malloc` call. You could allocate a `char (*)[50]` with one `malloc` call, but `char **` will _always_ use two levels of indirection.

Comment: It's only the third assignment.  I won't need to use any structures.

Comment: Also `size_t len = 0;` in a `struct` isn't valid C. (Perhaps you've been in C++ land for a bit too long... (; )

Comment: @Chris This is why I prefer working in C++ when I can help it. ;) I hope it's fixed now?

Comment: @muntoo - I prefer C personally, but I can't blame you. (And now you've got a loose `len` instead of `a.len` in your push function.)